# Locally free normal sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Consider a closed subscheme $Z$ of a scheme $X$. I know that if both $Z$ and $X$ are regular, then the conormal sheaf of $Z$ in $X$ is locally free. Does this still hold if only $Z$ is regular, and $X$ is singular? Or does there exist a simple counterexample? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conormal sheaf is locally free if and only if $Z$ is a locally complete intersection. The simplest counterexample with $X$ singular and $Z$ smooth is where $X$ is a quadratic cone and $Z$ is its ruling.

Comment: Thanks! So here $I/I^2$ is locally free of rank 1 except at the node. Another point of view is: if it is locally free, then $0\rightarrow I/I^2\rightarrow\Omega^1_X|_Z\rightarrow\Omega^1_Z\rightarrow 0$ is exact, and the middle term must also be locally free, which is possible only if $X$ is smooth. I suppose my confusion must be from the use of the term "local complete intersection"; I thought every smooth variety is a lci variety, but your example shows that it makes little sense to speak about lci without specifying the ambient space.

Comment: @Ferdi: When people say that $Z$ is lci, this usually understood as $Z$ is lci in a smooth ambient space.

Comment: Ah I see, this is quite useful to know. Thanks again, this was very helpful!

Comment: Do you know any reference for "the conormal sheaf is locally free if and only if $Z$ is a locally complete intersection"?

Comment: @ElíasGuisadoVillalgordo: Try to look this up in Hartshorne.